# Export a Rally Chart as jpeg

Tags: rally

Highcharts supports this via exportChart() method, but this is not supported by the rallychart?  Is there a work around for now?

```
    var chart = this.down('#chart');
    chart.exportChart({
              type: 'image/jpeg'
    });
```

Comment: The highcharts solution sends your data off to their server. Until we figure out what they have setup server side and duplicate it we are not planning on exposing that functionality. 
We are concerned that customers may not be aware that they are sending their data to a third party

Comment: OK. What are the options to export a chart as a jpeg?

Comment: For your own charts? We don't have anything set up to do that yet. I couldn't find an idea on ideas.rallydev.com but adding one is probably not a bad plan